# Frobenius splitting of Fano varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, characteristic-p, fano-varieties, counterexamples

Dear MO,

**Question 1.** Do you know of an example of a Fano variety which is **not** Frobenius split?

**Background**

(1) A variety $X$ in characteristic $p$ is called *Frobenius split* if there is a "$p$-th root" map $\sigma: \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X$, that is, an additive map satisfying $\sigma(f^p g) = f\sigma(g)$ and $\sigma(1) = 1$ (in particular, $\sigma(f^p) = f$, so that $\sigma$ is an $\mathcal{O}_X$-linear splitting of the Frobenius map $F: \mathcal{O}_X \to F_* \mathcal{O}_X$). Such varieties enjoy very nice properties, for example, $H^i(X, L)=0$ for $i>0$ for every ample line bundle $L$ on $X$.

In case $X$ is smooth and projective, $X$ is Frobenius split if and only if the map $F: H^{\dim X}(X, \omega_X) \to H^{\dim X}(X, F^* \omega_X)$ is nonzero. Note that $F^* \omega_X = \omega_X^p$. In particular, by Serre duality, $H^{\dim X}(X, \omega_X^p)^\vee = H^{0}(X, \omega_X^{1-p})$ is nonzero, that is, $(1-p)K_X$ is effective - so Frobenius split varieties are ,,on the Fano side''.

(2) A smooth projective variety $X$ is called *Fano* if $\omega_X^{-1}$ is ample. One can prove (Brion, Kumar *Frobenius splitting methods in geometry and representation theory*, Exercise 1.6.E5) that if $X$ is a Fano variety in characteristic $0$, then for $p\gg 0$ the reduction $X_p$ of $X$ mod $p$ is Fano and Frobenius split. This means that counterexamples to Question 1 might be difficult to find.

**Further questions**

Therefore, I am almost sure that, if counterexamples appear in the answers, they will have $\dim X$ (or other invariants of $X$, for example the degree of $K_X$ or its index) big compared to $p$. So I would like to ask:

**Question 2.** Can you find an effective bound $M = M(X) = M(\dim X, \ldots)$, depending on the dimension of $X$ and maybe other relatively simple invariants, such as the degree or index, such that whenever $X$ is a Fano variety in characteristic $p>M(X)$ then $X$ is Frobenius split. For example, does $M = 0$ (this is Question 1) or $M = n$ work?

*Note.* The $M = n$ case reminds me of the requirement in the theorem of Deligne-Illusie about decompositions of the de Rham complex that $p$ has to be $>n$.

Comment: Relevant: http://books.google.com/books?id=b3grB68Mn04C&lpg=PA55&ots=_r8tHRlWW3&dq=%5BBrion-Kumar%5D%20exercises%201.6.E&pg=PA55#v=onepage&q&f=true

Comment: I would guess that there do exist Fano varieties that are not F-split. As a possible counter-example (just a guess), I would suggest looking at the blow-up of projective 3-space along an ordinary elliptic curve.

Comment: Christian, I think that example can still be $F$-split (maybe depending on the embedding).  Certainly if the elliptic curve is projectively normally embedded, it will be compatibly Frobenius split with $\mathbb{P}^3$.  Then the blowup will be Frobenius split as well.  If it's not projectively normally embedded though, I'm not sure.

Comment: Oh, perhaps you meant a supersingular elliptic curve...

Comment: yes, sorry, I meant supersingular. I had the naive idea of blowing up s.th. that is not F-split might give a counter-example.

Comment: Christian, I agree.  That sounds possible, but I don't see how to prove it off the top of my head.

Comment: Christian, I don't think this can work - by a result of Elkies, an elliptic curve in characteristic 0 becomes supersingular at infinitely many primes, so this would contradict (2).

Comment: Piotr, thanks - that's a great argument! 

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For question 1, the following example works, and you'll see how to construct many more (in higher characteristic).

Set $k$ to be a perfect field of characteristic $2$.

$$X = \text{Proj } k[x,y,u,v]/\langle x^3+y^3+u^3+v^3 \rangle \subseteq \mathbb{P}^3_k.$$

---

###Fano check:###
I'm certain you already know this but...  Certainly $K_X \sim (K_{\mathbb{P}^3} + X)|_X \sim (-4H + 3H)|_X = -H|_X$ where $H$ is the hyperplane on $\mathbb{P}^3_k$.  Clearly also $X$ is smooth.  Thus $X$ is Fano.

---

###Frobenius splitting check:###
This is slightly more involved.  First we need a couple lemmas:

**Lemma:**  [Probably due to Karen Smith]  *A projective variety $X$ is Frobenius split if and only if some/every section ring with respect to an ample divisor*
$$S_X = \bigoplus_{n \geq 0} O_X(nA).$$
*is Frobenius split.*

The proof is pretty easy.  If $X$ is Frobenius split, so is $S_X$ (use the splitting on $S_X$ induced by that on $X$ on degrees divisible by $p$, throw the other degrees out).  For the converse direction, it's not hard to show that if $S_X$ has a Frobenius splitting, it then has an appropriately graded Frobenius splitting (basically, use the fact that $Hom_{S_X}(F_* S_X, S_X)$ is generated by appropriately graded maps).  It then induces maps on the associated sheaves.   Care must be taken since $\widetilde{F_* S_X} \neq F_* \widetilde S_X = F_* O_X$, but the latter is a summand of the former and this is enough.

Now for the next lemma.  If $J = \langle g_1, \dots, g_t \rangle$ is any ideal in a ring of characteristic $p$, we use $J^{[p]}$ to denote the ideal $\langle g_1^p, \dots, g_t^p \rangle$.

**Lemma:**  [Fedder's Criterion]  *Suppose $p = \text{char} k$, then a ring $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I$ is Frobenius split at a point $\mathbb{m} \in \text{Spec} k[x_1, dots, x_n]$ if and only if $I^{[p]} : I \nsubseteq \mathbb{m}^{[p]}$.*

See Lemma 1.6 in *$F$-purity and rational singularity* by Richard Fedder (1983, Transactions of the AMS).  It's quite easy, but maybe more than I want to explain.

**Corollary:**  *If $p = 2$ and $I = \langle f \rangle$, then $R$ is Frobenius split at $\mathbb{m}$ if and only if* $f \notin \mathbb{m}^{[2]}$. *(in other characteristics, you have( $f^{p-1} \notin \mathbb{m}^{[p]}$)*.

Ok, now we verify that $X$ is not Frobenius split.  Consider the section ring given our embedding, $S_X = k[x,y,u,v]/\langle x^3 + y^3 + u^3 + v^3 \rangle$.  It is sufficient to show that $S_X$ is not Frobenius split, and that we can check at the origin since $S_X$ is a graded ring.  Then we simply observe that
$$
x^3+y^3+u^3+v^3 \in \langle x^2, y^2, u^2, v^2 \rangle.
$$

---

##Generalizations, question 2, and further references##

The result you mention about Fanos is actually generalized to log-Fano varieties in this paper:  [Globally $F$-regular and log Fano varieties](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0404) due to Karen Smith and myself.  Log Fano's are varieties where $-K_X$ is not necessarily ample, but where it is *close*.  Some additional discussion of the lemmas above can also be found here.

Lots of people in commutative algebra have been exploring question of when various rings are $F$-split.  For example, see [THIS PAPER](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.2425.pdf) of Daniel Hernandez and references.  I know there are people exploring exactly when graded hypersurfaces are $F$-split = $F$-pure but this is not public yet.

In terms of Question 2: effective bounds, I don't know any great ones off the top of my head.  I'll try to get back to you on this.